# Audacity not working anymore

Tags: launcher, alsa, audacity

I had installed Audacity and everything was working fine until it stopped opening.

The only change that I can think it could have affected audacity, is that I installed pyaudio, but I am not sure how could it have 'damaged' audacity.

I already purged, autoremoved and re-installed audacity from ppa.

Still does not open.

When I try to run from the terminal I get the following:

```
marco@marco-Satellite-P55t-B:~$ audacity &
[1] 29460
marco@marco-Satellite-P55t-B:~$ ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
audacity: symbol lookup error: audacity: undefined symbol: Pa_GetStreamHostApiType
```

I just see the logo of Audacity popping in my screen and then disappearing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best Regards,

Marco.

Edit: solved it following these instructions:

https://sukritkalra94.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/audacity-fails-with-the-pa_getstreamhostapitype-error/

Comment: Does it work if you install it from the repo?

Comment: Do you mean with the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity`

I tried installing it like that, but I keep having the same error

Comment: I just fixed it following these instructions:

https://sukritkalra94.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/audacity-fails-with-the-pa_getstreamhostapitype-error/

Thanks !

Comment: Hi @MarcoM, you should answer your own question, and then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it following these instructions:

https://sukritkalra94.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/audacity-fails-with-the-pa_getstreamhostapitype-error/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Similar but different bug, Audacity locks up after a power failure by displaying Audacity logo over a grey popup window "Audacity already running, can't run two copies".  There is a lock file at **/var/tmp/audacity-*myusername*/audacity-lock-*myusername*** that does not get cleaned up after a hard shutdown.  It will frustratingly prevent any new instances of audacity from being launched, even if you have no current instances running.  Delete this file, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had changed the "Keyboard input method system" to "XIM" and when I changed it back to "none" and restarted my computer Audacity worked again. Note that you can also select "IBus" instead of "none" and it should work fine.
On Ubuntu go to "Settings", "Region and Language", "Manage Installed Languages" and there you will find the "Keyboard input method system" settings.